# R update df1 values based ond df2 in different format

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am trying to find a scalable solution to update a data.frame based on another data.frame. Here a minimal example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(c("a","b","b","b","c"),c(1,1,1,2,2),as.numeric(c(0.2,0.6,0.6,0.8,0.4))))
colnames(df1) <- c("ID1", "ID2","Value")

> df1
  ID1 ID2 Value
1   a   1   0.2
2   b   1   0.6
3   b   1   0.6
4   b   2   0.8
5   c   2   0.4

df2 <- data.frame(cbind(2),0,0.45,0.5)
colnames(df2) <- c("ID2", "a","b","c")

> df2
   ID2 a    b    c
1   2  0  0.45  0.5
```

Now I would like to update the values of df1 by using df2 values to get to the following result:

```
   ID1 ID2 Value
1   a   1   0.2
2   b   1   0.6
3   b   1   0.6
4   b   2   0.45
5   c   2   0.5
```

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, lets get rid of `cbind` while creating your data sets so it won't convert to matrix first and mess up the classes.

```
df1 <- data.frame(c("a","b","b","b","c"),c(1,1,1,2,2),c(0.2,0.6,0.6,0.8,0.4))
colnames(df1) <- c("ID1", "ID2","Value")
df2 <- data.frame(2,0,0.45,0.5)
colnames(df2) <- c("ID2", "a","b","c")
```

Then, I would convert your second data set to a long format first and then update in place `df1`

```
library(data.table) #v>=1.9.6
ldf2 <- melt(setDT(df2), 1)
setDT(df1)[ldf2, Value := i.value, on = c(ID1 = "variable", ID2 = "ID2")]
df1
#    ID1 ID2 Value
# 1:   a   1  0.20
# 2:   b   1  0.60
# 3:   b   1  0.60
# 4:   b   2  0.45
# 5:   c   2  0.50
```